# selenium-server: Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED

Tags: windows, symfony, selenium, codeception

Attempts to install Selenium Server as a service (using nssm) in Windows 10 fail with `Unexpected status SERVICE_PAUSED` on `nssm start selenium-server`. Selenium is selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar.  nssm is 2.24. OS is Windows 10, 1511, 32-bit.

Event viewer says

> Service selenium-server ran for less than 1500 milliseconds. Restart
>   will be delayed by 16000 milliseconds.

The objective is to run acceptance tests of a Symfony application using codeception. PhantomJS has been abandoned as it does not accommodate javascript popups.

Answer (score 1):

Returning to the question & doing some more searching revealed the [solution here](http://unintelligible.org/blog/2009/07/28/installing-selenium-rc-as-a-windows-service/).  While this is quite old, the key features remain the same (be sure to replace the `*` to provide the precise file name of the server jar, e.g., `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta4.jar`):

1. In the registry, modify the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\selenium-server\Parameters\AppDirectory` to show the directory where the selenium-server-standalone*.jar is saved.
2. Also modify the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\selenium-server\Parameters\AppParameters` to `-Xrs -jar selenium-server-standalone*.jar -port 8888`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get selenium-server service to start by *only* having the following in the "AppParameters" registry field that geoB mentions:

```
-jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

It seems the -Xrs isn't a valid parameter and was keeping the jar from starting. Same for -interactive (if you're following Selenium's website instructions (https://kb.op5.com/display/HOWTOs/Setting+up+Selenium+Server+on+Microsoft+Windows)