# Codeception test of browser download dialog

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

A codeception acceptance test of a file download does not "see" a browser's file download dialog box.  The test failure screen capture shows only the form.
The test includes the following:

```
$I->click('Reports');
$I->click('Most recent contacts (PDF)');
$I->selectOption('form select[name="select_center[center]"]', 'Truckee');
$I->click('Submit');
$I->wait(5);
$I->see('Open with');
```

If these steps are followed in the Symfony test (or dev) environment, the dialog box appears in less than 2 seconds.

The Selenium driver is not an option - it [cannot be loaded as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849010/selenium-server-unexpected-status-service-paused) in Windows 10.

Comment: What are you using instead of Selenium?

Comment: @Naktibalda Phantomjs.

Comment: see method can't see dialogue boxes, it only looks at the page source.

Comment: Is it then not possible to test the presence of a browser's dialog box?